# ob_start(); in php?

Tags: php

When using `on_start()` does it make any difference to do,

```
// ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION
ob_start();
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

Or is this exactly the same,

```
// ENABLE GZIP COMPRESSION
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

I ask as with the first example my website seems to speed up a bit.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, PHP run from PHP-FPM automatically starts output buffering. Then Nginx/Apache gzips it and sends it to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do either:

```
ob_start();
```

or:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

But not both.  You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']` to see if the user agent accepts gzip encodings:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== false)
   ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
else
    ob_start();
```

Comment: No need to actually check if the client accepts gzip, the handler will do this for you and not use gzip if it is not accepted:  `Note:

In PHP 4.0.4, ob_gzhandler() was introduced to facilitate sending gz-encoded data to web browsers that support compressed web pages. ob_gzhandler() determines what type of content encoding the browser will accept and will return its output accordingly.`

Answer (score 0):

The first starts two layers of output buffering. Waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

No difference at all. ob_start() is stackable. Which means the second ob_start() will simply append it's contents to the first ob_start() when flushed.